# Cannot login to Stack Overflow ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: support, login, google, oauth2

From work, I could login. A few days ago I was disconnected. Now I try to login via Google, from work, and I am redirected on a:

> This site can't be reached.
>   The webpage at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=... might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

I get the same behavior both from Chrome and from IE.

Any ideas?

I also tried to connect via email/password, but either I don't remember it, or you are allowed to use only one mechanism to login at a time (so no, I didn't try the 'forgot' option, I don't want to be blocked or something).

Comment: Possibly related: [Google auth seems broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324447/289905).

Comment: A different error there @Xufox, but might be related, thank you. There is no feedback there however...

Comment: Have you tried Firefox or Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Installing something new on the environment I am on is very cumbersome, so that's not an option.

Comment: The error code indicates that the problem is probably in your office (misbehaving proxy) rather than at SO or Google.

Comment: yea i dont get the tunnel error.

Comment: TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED means that it is a local problem. We have that stuff in our school too, it comes from the proxy that is checking you are not watching... eh.. non-work-related videos at work. I don't know why it blocked Stack Overflow, maybe a mistake?

Comment: In cases like this, I use Firefox Portable set to "Don't use proxy", but I don't know if your network allows traffic that does not go through the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Jobs lands me on the same login page I think, so same behavior. I must check with the local IT then, I guess...

Comment: I have found out that if my browser has a SO tab open in Chrome my Windows L2TP vpn won't connect. Maybe related?

Comment: It's a problem with my local work IT.

Security decided that they do not support this kind of Google authentication no more...

Comment: @gsamaras since this is possibly something others would encounter, I think that is worthy of a self-answer

Comment: I self-answered, got downvoted, thus my comment. @psubsee2003